# How can I insert the contents of a Word document inside another word file in a certain position?

Tags: c#, ms-word, .net-4.0, office-interop

I need to populate a Word Document according to a predefined template. In this layout there are three blocks: in the first and third block there are strings to be replaced by other strings according to certain procedures and it works.Between these two blocks I need to insert the contents of another file word, which is composed, in this case, of tables: I'm looking for a way to extract the contents of this file and add it to a certain position of the document.

Comment: Does the Range.InsertFile method not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement for one of my tool.

I had a Word template contains tables which had to populate contents from another Word document.

I followed the below approach.

I read the contents from the source document to a list.

And I iterated through the template table , each cell by cell ( my cell contained header text ). Like below.

```
foreach (Cell aCell in aRow.Cells)
                        {
                            switch (aCell.Range.Text.Split(':')[0])
                            {
                                case "Cell Header Text":
                                    var cellHeaderText= contents.Where(p => p.CellName.Contains("Cell Header Text"));
                                    foreach (var p in cellText)
                                    {
                                        aCell.Range.InsertAfter("\r" + p.CellValue.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Trim() + "\r");

                                    }
                                    break;


                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
}
```

if you dont need to place a header text, then you can add a bookmark in the cell. And then check   if (aCell.Range.Text.Contains("bookmark name")) {} .
Inside the if loop, you can replace the book mark with the actual text or any attachment.

Hope it helps. if yes, plz mark it as an answer. thanks